# Removing up to 4 spaces from a string

Tags: java, string

I have an array of Strings Im looping through. For each string, I need to remove up to 4 spaces from the beginning. In other words, if there are only 2 spaces, I remove 2. If there are 6 spaces I remove 4. How can I specify this in the loop?

```
for(int i=0; i<stringArray.length; i++) {
    newString = REMOVE UP TO 4 SPACES FROM stringArray[i];
    stringArray[i] = newString;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds a LOT like a homework question--if so would you please tag it as such.  It will help people answer you in a more appropriate manner.

Comment: This is NOT a homework question. Sorry :L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex is the best tool for this job. I will explain it step by step:

#### Introduction

```
System.out.println(
    "# one ## two ### three #### four"
        .replaceAll("##", "@@")
);
//  "# one @@ two @@# three @@@@ four"
```

The above snippet should give you a good idea of how [`replaceAll`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) works: it replaces all occurrences of `"##"` with `"@@"`.

#### Pattern

As it turns out, `replaceAll` is a regex-based method: the first argument is a special *pattern* string, and the second argument is a special *replacement* string. The next snippet illustrates the idea:

```
System.out.println(
    "# one ## two ### three #### four"
        .replaceAll("#{2}", "@@")
);
//  "# one @@ two @@# three @@@@ four"
```

Now we used `"#{2}"` as the first argument. Rather intuitively, in regex this means "`#` repeated exactly twice"; this is exactly the same pattern we had before, which is why we also get the same result.

#### Range

The bounded repetition syntax in regex is actually quite expressive: instead of exact repetition, we can also define a range as follows:

```
System.out.println(
    "# one ## two ### three #### four"
        .replaceAll("#{1,3}", ":")
);
//  ": one : two : three :: four"
```

Rather intuitively, `#{1,3}` means "`#` repeated between 1 and 3 times".

#### Greed

Now note that regex repetition by default is *greedy*: it tries to match more if possible. This is illustrated by the following:

```
System.out.println(
    "# one ## two ### three #### four"
        .replaceAll("#{2,3}", ":")
);
//  ": one : two : three :# four"
```

Note that `####` is replaced into `:#`. This is because the first 3 was taken by the first replacement, leaving only 1 left. Had `#{2,3}` only taken 2 `#` the first time, there would've been another `#` the second time, but since it's *greedy*, it took 3 `#` the first time, leaving it no chance to take the last `#`!

#### First

Now let's try another example as follows:

```
System.out.println(
    "=====5====4===3==2=1"
        .replaceAll("={1,4}", ":")
);
//  "::5:4:3:2:1"
```

Now let's say that we only want the first `={1,4}` match to be replaced with `":"`.

```
System.out.println(
    "=====5====4===3==2=1"
        .replaceFirst("={1,4}", ":")
);
//  ":=5====4===3==2=1"
```

Voila! Everything works as expected!

#### Anchor

Now let's look at the next example:

```
System.out.println(
    "0=====5====4===3==2=1"
        .replaceFirst("={1,4}", ":")
);
//  "0:=5====4===3==2=1"
```

The replacement is still doing what it's supposed to do, but let's suppose that we only to match `={1,4}` at the beginning of the string. Fortunately for us, regular expression has a way to express this: we can *anchor* the pattern at the beginning of the string, which is denoted by `^`.

```
System.out.println(
    "0=====5====4===3==2=1"
        .replaceFirst("^={1,4}", ":")
);
//  "0=====5====4===3==2=1"

System.out.println(
    "=====5====4===3==2=1"
        .replaceFirst("^={1,4}", ":")
);
//  ":=5====4===3==2=1"

System.out.println(
    "===3==2=1"
        .replaceFirst("^={1,4}", ":")
);
//  ":3==2=1"
```

Voila! Everything works as expected!

---

#### Going back to the answer

And now we have enough information to answer the original question!

```
stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].replaceFirst("^ {1,4}", "");
```

So the pattern `^ {1,4}` means:

- Anchored at the beginning of the string with `^`...
- ...between 1 to 4 space characters, taking more if possible

We then replace the first occurrence of such a match with the empty string, essentially removing it.

---

#### More learning resources

That was a beginner's introduction to regular expressions basics. There are still many aspects to this wonderful world that haven't been explored yet.

#### References

- [Java Tutorials/Essential Classes/Regular Expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/)
- [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/)

  - [Repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)
  - [Anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html)

#### Related questions

- Coming eventually

Comment: Excellent, detailed answer. Someone else had the answer, but this had the detailed explanation and allowed me to really understand what I was doing. Thank you so much for taking the time to do this!

Comment: To others: please don't revise this for me. I'll correct typos etc on my own with next revision.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].replaceFirst ("^ {0,4}", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you care about trailing spaces?

You could check it against a regular expression to see if it matches 4 or more spaces in front, and use substring to clip off the first 4 spaces. Else if there are less than 4 spaces in front (does not match RegEx) just use string.trim() in Java.