# Counting spaces infront of a String

Tags: java, string

Recently I asked this question: [Removing up to 4 spaces from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3199449/removing-up-to-4-spaces-from-a-string)

and it works just fine. I am interested however in counting the number of spaces I have removed as well. How can I do this? Count the number of spaces removed using this?

```
stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].replaceFirst ("^ {0,4}", "");
```

Basically, I need to be able to remove **up to** 4 spaces from a string, and then save in an int how many spaces were actually removed. Any help on this would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one simple way:

```
int oldLen = stringArray[i].length();
stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].replaceFirst ("^ {0,4}", "");
int spacesRemoved = oldLen - stringArray[i].length();
```

Comment: `spacesRemoved` will always end up `0` or negative using this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
int oldLength = stringArray[i].length();
stringArray[i] = stringArray[i].replaceFirst("^ {0,4}", "");
int spacesRemoved = oldLength - stringArray[i].length();
```